How to get the mounted point full path while it has space in bash
I have an UBUNTU installation USB disk.
The disk name is "UBUNTU 22_0" and will be mounted on "/run/media/UBUNTU 22_0-sda1".
There is a space on it so the command "df | grep /dev/sda | awk '{ print $6 }'" is not work.
root@host:~# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        2972456 1629696   1169092  59% /
devtmpfs          733972       4    733968   1% /dev
tmpfs             981396       0    981396   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs             392560    9544    383016   3% /run
tmpfs               4096       0      4096   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs             981400      20    981380   1% /tmp
tmpfs             981396     232    981164   1% /var/volatile
tmpfs             196276       0    196276   0% /run/user/0
/dev/mmcblk2p2     65390       0     65390   0% /run/media/fake-mmcblk2p2
/dev/mmcblk1p1 122078208 3231488 118846720   3% /run/media/mmcblk1p1
/dev/mmcblk2p1     65390   37516     27874  58% /run/media/boot-mmcblk2p1
/dev/mmcblk2p4   4129072    1084   3894212   1% /run/media/data-mmcblk2p4
/dev/sda1        3992256 3833984    158272  97% /run/media/UBUNTU 22_0-sda1

root@host:~# df | grep /dev/sda | awk '{ print $6 }'
/run/media/UBUNTU


findmnt -S /dev/sda1 or findmnt -nr -o target -S /dev/sda1  see Check Where a disk is mounted for more info.

1. Only if you're sure about our request:
Warning! Running df /dev/DEVICE will return informations about DEVICE only if they is mounted!! If not, df /dev/DEVICE will silently return informations about /dev ( or / if /dev is not a mount point ), whithout throwing an warning or an error about not mounted. Then
If you're asking for

where are mounted /dev/sda1

and you are sure that /dev/sda1 is mounted, you could follow:
1.1. Into variables
As I'm doing this kind of things, mostly for storing results into variables, I often use:
{ read _;read -r _ fstyp tot use fre _ mpnt;}< <(df -TPk /dev/sda1)

So I get immediately 5 useful variables:
declare -p tot use fre mpnt fstyp

declare -- tot="2268255"
declare -- use="1977866"
declare -- fre="129159"
declare -- mpnt="/run/media/UBUNTU 22_0-sda1"
declare -- fstyp="ext4"

Without the use of external tools.
But if you just want to store the mount point, you could:
{ read _;read -r mpnt;}< <(df --output=target /dev/sda1)
echo "$mpnt"

/run/media/UBUNTU 22_0-sda1

And if you find this syntax not sexy, you could use mapfile:
mapfile -t mpnt < <(df --output=target /dev/sda1)
echo "${mpnt[1]}"

/run/media/UBUNTU 22_0-sda1

2. If you're not sure /dev/DEVICE is acually mounted.
Then you have to ask system for knowing this!
2.1. By using df and grep.
Well, near same solution, then:
read -r _ fstyp tot use fre _ mpnt < <(df -TPk|grep "^/dev/sda1\b")

Then again, I get immediately 5 useful variables:
declare -p tot use fre mpnt fstyp

declare -- tot="2268255"
declare -- use="1977866"
declare -- fre="129159"
declare -- mpnt="/run/media/UBUNTU 22_0-sda1"
declare -- fstyp="ext4"

2.2. By reading directly /proc (pure bash):
But you could read kernel variables directly on /proc pseudo filesystem:
while read -r dev dmnt _; do case $dev in
        /dev/sda1 ) printf -v mpnt "%b" "$dmnt" ;;
    esac; done < /proc/mounts
echo "$mpnt"

/run/media/UBUNTU 22_0-sda1

3. Linux tools for inquiring system:
There are 2 other util-linux tools you could use for this:
3.1. findmnt
findmnt -S /dev/sda1 -no TARGET

Where result code will be not null if /dev/sda1 isn't mounted.
if mpnt=$(findmnt -S /dev/sda1 -no TARGET);then
    echo "sda1 mounted on $mpnt"
fi

3.2. lsblk
lsblk -no MOUNTPOINT /dev/sda1

But lsblk will silently return an empty line if not mounted, whithout throwing an error:
if mpnt=$(lsblk -no MOUNTPOINT /dev/sda1);[[ $mpnt ]];then
    echo "sda1 mounted on $mpnt"
fi


Any df should let you specify which filesystem you want to see, and with GNU df,  you can format the output:
df --output=target /dev/sda1 | sed '1d'


Note that the OP grep /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1. It could be that your solution does not fully match their requirements.

@RenaudPacalet Worst: If /dev/sda1 isn't mounted, then df will return /dev instead of nothing or an error!  Try df /dev/null and see my answer

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub Would it? My df errors with "no such file or directory" for a non-existing mount, and for an unmounted one, it shows not /dev, but another device.

@BenjaminW. Yes, it will! If you run df --output=target /dev/sda and block device /dev/sda exist AND insn't mounted, then df will return /dev and no error!

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub Mine doesn't. It shows the information for another filesystem under /dev, but not /dev itself.

With your shown samples and with GNU awk's match function which supports array you can try following.
df | awk '
match($0,/^\/dev\/sda1[[:space:]]+.*[0-9]+%[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]]+)/,arr){
  print arr[1]
}
'


As you use GNU awk you could as well simplify by replacing [[:space:]] with \s and [^[:space:]] with \S. And note that the OP greps /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1.

Useful suggestion, @RenaudPacalet

Using any awk regardless of which characters appear in the data (other than newline of course) or how long any given field is:
$ cat file | awk 'NR==1{p=index($0,"Mounted on"); next} $1=="/dev/sda1"{print substr($0,p)}'
/run/media/UBUNTU 22_0-sda1

All that relies on is that Mounted on appears once as the last header in the first line of the df output and that the value for that field starts lined up under that header as shown in the sample input.
Change $1=="/dev/sda1" to $0 ~ "/dev/sda" if you REALLY wanted a full-line regexp comparison as you were doing with grep, but I doubt it, or index($0,"/dev/sda") == 1 if you actually want to test for lines starting with that string.

Reading columns widths in headline is a nice idea! You could replace cat file | by LANG=C df | (maybe followed by a newline).

Do it by character position instead of field number.
Also, there's no need to use grep when awk can match the first field itself.
df | awk '$1 == "/dev/sda" { print substr($0, 49); }'


This will not work, because the formatting (field widths) of df depends on max length of other devices.

For this aproach, in one awk operation, you could: df | awk '$1 == "/dev/sda1" { str="";for(i=6;i<=NF;i++) { str=str" "$i };print substr(str,2) }'

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub I thought of that, but it won't work if there are 2+ spaces and/or TAB characters between words.

@Wiimm I didn't realize that. I assumed there were fixed field widths, and longer fields would just overflow. And since /dev/sda1 is known to fit, it wouldn't overflow.

The path you are interested in, starts 2  only % in the line, separated by one character (space or tab). Hence you could do a
df | awk ' /\/dev\/sda/ { sub(/.*% /, ""); print }'

UPDATE : My solution would fail if the mount point contains a percent sign followed by a space (for instance /mnt/foo% bar) or has a space at the last character (for instance /mnt/something%). The awk approach in general would also fail if the mount point contains a newline character. I don't know whether such mount points are allowed at all. At least I have never encountered such a case.

This would fail with a mount point named /opt/foo%bar%sda.

@RenaudPacalet : No, this would be caught, because I am checking for a space after the percent sign. However, your comment made me add a remark to my answer. /opt/foosda% would cause trouble. I could catch this by matching the line for /dev/sda[^%]*$ instead of looking for just /dev/sda, but this is a pretty unrealistic border case.

Yes, sorry, I should have added spaces in my example. Anyway, with /opt/foo% bar% sda it would fail. And note that as it is almost free you should probably anchor the /\/dev\/sda/ regex to the beginning of the line (/^\/dev\/sda/).

@RenaudPacalet : Anchoring makes sense, but since the OP didn't anchor either, I focused on the question's problem, i.e. that $6 does not work, if we have spaces there. In any case - if someone creates a mountpoint with % , it's not really sane in the first place, and the attempt of the OP did not deal with a space in the mount point either. Anyway, I described this restriction in my answer.

The following assumes that the 5 first columns do not contain spaces on your system and that the mount point is the rest of the line. Different from other solutions there are no other assumptions about the starting positions of the fields, the absence of % characters in other columns than Use, the fact that you are interested in only /dev/sda1, the absence of string sda in other columns than the first, etc.
If awk or sed are involved there is usually no need for grep. You can use them to select the lines starting with /dev/sda, delete the 5 first words plus the following spaces, and print. Example with GNU sed:
df | sed -nE '/^\/dev\/sda/s/^(\S+\s+){5}//p'

With any POSIX sed:
df | sed -n '/^\/dev\/sda/s/^\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}[[:space:]]\{1,\}\)\{5\}//p'

With GNU awk:
df | awk '/^\/dev\/sda/ {sub(/^(\S+\s+){5}/,""); print}'

With any POSIX awk:
df | awk '/^\/dev\/sda/ {sub(/^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){5}/,""); print}'



If you want to find exactly /dev/sda (not /dev/sdaX), you may have to add \b  in your RE, 2. You may use something else than / for addressing in sed: Try this:  df | sed -nE '\_^/dev/sda1\b_s/^(\S+\s+){5}//p', and this  df | sed -n '\_^/dev/sda\b_s/^\([^[:space:]]\+[[:space:]]\+\)\{5\}//p'... (You may prefer ; or | to _ ;-).


I don't want anything else than providing a solution to the OP. As the OP use grep /dev/sda I simply stick to this. They may want all /dev/sdaX or not, this was not specified in the OP. I did not use custom addressing delimiters because in this case it saves only one character and I doubt it makes things easier to understand for a sed beginner.

Because it is the last column, you can just add additional columns to your print:
df | grep /dev/sda | awk '{ print $6,$7,$8 }'
/run/media/UBUNTU 22_0-sda1 

or, without the grep:
df | awk '/dev.sda/{ print $6,$7,$8 }'

Or try sed :
df | sed -n 's/.dev.sda1.*% //p'


And another alternative that won't depend on knowing the terminal width/counting columns and skipping the unnecessary grep:
df  | awk -F"% " '/sda/{print $2}'
/run/media/UBUNTU 22_0-sda


This would also print a tmpfs filesystem mounted on /var/nasdac and it would fail with a mount point named /opt/foo% bar% sda.

This will match mount points that contain sda in label: mkfs -L "old_sda1_bkup" /dev/sdc1. So once mounted on /usr/media/old_sda1_bkup, your command will match both sdc and sda.

Another solution using file /proc/mounts instead of command df.
printf %b "$( awk ' $1=="/dev/sda" {print $2}' /proc/mounts )"

The mount point is the second string. If it contains special characters they are escaped. \040 is used for a space. Format %b of printf interprets these escapes.
If you want to store the result in a variable, then add -v varname:
printf -v VARNAME %b "$( awk ' $1=="/dev/sda" {print $2}' /proc/mounts )"

